# Getting error after installing Cx_Oracle in Python 3.x evn in linux redhat, excuted Command is python manage.py migrate

Tags: python, linux, django

Trying to replicate django first project at step 02
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial02/

Database set up

**Executed command** : python manage.py migrate

**Error** : *ImportError: No module named 'django.db.backends.util'*

**Trace sing**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 4, in <module>
    import sqlserver_ado
  File "/home/Username/.virtualenvs/django_v1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django_mss                                                                           ql-1.7-py3.5.egg/sqlserver_ado/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from . import patches  # NOQA
  File "/home/Username/.virtualenvs/django_v1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django_mss                                                                           ql-1.7-py3.5.egg/sqlserver_ado/patches.py", line 7, in <module>
    from django.db.backends.util import CursorWrapper
ImportError: No module named 'django.db.backends.util'
(django_v1)[Username@njundbnp152 Firstapp]$ python manage.py migrate
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 4, in <module>
    import sqlserver_ado
  File "/home/Username/.virtualenvs/django_v1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django_mss                                                                           ql-1.7-py3.5.egg/sqlserver_ado/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from . import patches  # NOQA
  File "/home/Username/.virtualenvs/django_v1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django_mss                                                                           ql-1.7-py3.5.egg/sqlserver_ado/patches.py", line 7, in <module>
    from django.db.backends.util import CursorWrapper
ImportError: No module named 'django.db.backends.util'
```

**pip list:**

```
Django (1.9.4)
django-mssql (1.7)
django-pyodbc (0.3.0)
djangotoolbox (1.8.0)
pip (7.1.2)
pyodbc (3.0.10)
pypyodbc (1.3.3)
setuptools (18.2)
wheel (0.24.0)
```

**Database settings are as follows**

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'NAME': 'Name',
        'ENGINE': 'sqlserver_ado',
```

Comment: import django.db.backends.util to manage.py again
Error : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 4, in <module>
    import sqlserver_ado
  File "/home/Username/.virtualenvs/django_v1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django_mssql-1.7-py3.5.egg/sqlserver_ado/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from . import patches  # NOQA
  File "/home/Username/.virtualenvs/django_v1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django_mssql-1.7-py3.5.egg/sqlserver_ado/patches.py", line 7, in <module>
    from django.db.backends.util import CursorWrapper
ImportError: No module named 'django.db.backends.util'

Comment: I am using this in linux redhat